# How do i plot secondary X axis in python with pandas dataframe using cufflinks?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

From available documentations, I see there is a cuff links method to plot secondary Y axis, setting `secondary_Y = True` to plot secondary Y axis, however don't see any related method to plot secondary X axis, can somebody  point me on how to get this done ?

For ex:

```
   result.iplot(x='time', secondary_y='time_cdut')
```

However, we dont have any option to plot `secondary_Y`

-Thx

Comment: I think this option is not available yet, but PR are welcome :)